# Adding statements inside curly braces change the code functionality?

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to C++, I am trying to replicate a code from C++ reference that turns spaces in a string to dashes. Here's the code

```
void sp_to_dash(const char *str){
    while(*str){
        if(*str==' ')
            cout<<("%c", '-');

        else
            cout<<("%c", *str);
            str++;

    }
}

int main(){
    sp_to_dash("hello world how are you");
    int j;
    cin>>j;
    return 0;
}
```

Now this works perfectly, the output I get is 
OUTPUT: 
`hello-world-how-are-you`

However when I enclose the code in `sp_to_dash` function in curly braces like this

```
void sp_to_dash(const char *str) {
    while (*str) {
        if (*str==' ') {
            cout << ("%c", '-');
        } else {
            cout << ("%c", *str);
            str++;
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get is an infinite loop of dashes, I don't understand why that is, Can anyone explain to me why adding code in curly braces like this triggers an infinite loop?

Comment: It does change. Without curly braces, else only guards the statement right below. With your new braces, else guards both statements. Your indentation is misleading

Comment: I always am amused by such questions: "I changed the code; The code does something different; Why?"

Comment: Usually compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` would give you some "misleading indentation" warning...

Comment: By the way you should learn how to use a debugger too.

Comment: On a side note, you don't need to use `printf` style format parameters with the `<<` operator. You can replace `cout<<("%c", '-')` and `cout<<("%c", *str)` with `cout<<'-'` and `cout<<*str`, respectively, and still get the same output. Your original code "works" due to the nature of the `,` comma operator, not `"%c"`.

Comment: I may sound heretical, but I can't stand that formatting where the `{` is on the same line as the code.   Give me the `{` standing by its lonesome any day.

Comment: Looking at the OP's profile, the profile suggests a Python programmer.  If so, C++ is *not* Python.  Indentation in C++ doesn't mean that the statement belongs to the `if` or the `else`.  Indentation in C++ is only used for readability.

Comment: The code is bad (why not `std::string`?!), but the question is good, upvoting :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indentation is misleading. There can only be a single statement under an if or else branch. To put several, it must be a compound statement (in curly braces). So this

```
    else
        cout<<("%c", *str);
        str++;
```

... is equivalent to this

```
    else
        cout<<("%c", *str);
    str++;
```

So adding the curly braces changes the programs flow of control, which is why you get different behavior. Many (possibly most) would recommend to *always* add curly braces, even on single statement branches, to future proof it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the az indentation is confusing. Without braces only the first line is executed and `str++` is not intended to be part of branch else but be executed in every cycle. In the second case the str is increment ed only venue the current character is not '-' which is true at the end.

Furthermore it will continue reading the memory after it reached the end of the string. This menory area belongs to other variable or maybe other process this it can be handled as random characters from your perspective.